# How to pass a path to function

Tags: linux, shell

Function parses path argument

```
gzip_files (){
  echo 'gzip files'
  echo $1
}

gzip_files '/var/www/bak/*/*'
```

## output

```
gzip files
/var/www/bak/site1/ini /var/www/bak/site1/db /var/www/bak/site2/ini /var/www/bak/site2/site /var/www/bak/site2/ini
```

How to get the output to be

```
gzip files
/var/www/bak/*/*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to quote the `$1`:

```
echo "$1"
```

or else the content of the variable will interpreted as if you entered it directly, that is the wildcards `*` in

```
echo /var/www/bak/*/*
```

will be expanded.

Answer (score 2):

Quote the variable expansion to prevent shell globbing from taking place:

```
gzip_files (){
  echo 'gzip files'
  echo "$1"
}
```

Note that, if you want to use multiple positional parameters, you need to use `$@` to refer all of them instead of just the first one by `$1`:

```
gzip_files (){
  echo 'gzip files'
  echo "$@"
}
```